# Using Selenium in Python to select/copy a text

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, text

```
<div class="top-info">
"Vote : 42 - Out : 84 - Rate : 3 - Strategie - "
<a href="/site-Ezy+1.29++Serveur+FUN++Serveur+AnkaLike+-44578">Info</a>
</div>
```

Hi, I'm trying to select and copy the out which equals 84 in this case number from this code but I don't know what to do?

Comment: please include your current code

Comment: Update the question with a bit more of the outerHTML, your code trials and the error you are seeing.

Comment: And are you needing to search for div containing Out :  number or specifically Out 
 :  84? And do you need the whole string? <White space before : was removed in comment!>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you would need to get a reference to the html element that contains the needed text. You could use the `driver.find_element_by_class_name('top-info')` method from the webdriver (assuming the page uses this class only once). You can find more HTML elements with selenium [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

When you have a reference to that HTML element you can access the inner text by using the following method on your previously found element:

`text = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')`

The last thing you need to do is split your string in order to get the number you need. You could do something like this:

`text.split(":")[2].split(" ")[0]`

This splits the text first at all colons, then it would split the third part at all spaces and finally grabs the first part of the result. This would give you the number 84 in your example.